# Mongoose not enforcing type with model save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my schema I have:

```
var CpuSchema = new Schema({
    timeStamp : { type : Date, index: true },
    avaiable : Boolean,
    status : String,
```

In my function to save a document:

```
function saveCpu(cpuResult) {
    console.log("THE TYPE IS: " + typeof(cpuResult.metrics["15m"].data));
    var cpu = new Cpu ({
        timeStamp : cpuResult.timestamp,
        avaiable : cpuResult.available,
        status : cpuResult.metrics["15m"].data,
```

But in the output model's save():

```
THE TYPE IS: number
Mongoose: cpus.insert({ __v: 0, metrics: [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ], _id: ObjectId("5397bcf1803ee2e535776934"), status: '0.05', avaiable: true, timeStamp: new Date("Wed, 11 Jun 2014 02:22:06 GMT") }) {}
```

It is not showing a validation error for `status : String,` because `cpuResult.metrics["15m"].data` is a type `Number` and not a `String`... but instead converting the number to a string. Why is this? I would like validation on types and I thought this was automatic in Mongoose without custom validation needed.

Comment: You status type is String and all JavaScript objects inherently have a `.toString()` method which is being implicitly called.

Comment: Even if `THE TYPE IS: number`? This doesn't make sense because Mongoose Schemas use types. If the above is true, why does Mongoose use types at all? I am under the assumption it uses types and checks for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so possibly more information than just a comment. You have asked for a `String` type on your field. As such mongoose does what it generally should and makes sure this is a string.

All JavaScript objects, which your number actually is an object, inherit a `.toString()` method. So what is happening here is that method is being called and the data goes in as a string.

Try this in your favorite REPL:

```
var data = {};
data.number = 1;

data.number.toString();
```

That shows you that the method is valid.

The reverse is not true though as a String cannot implicitly be cast as a Number. So if you defined a Number for your schema field a String would actually fail validation:

```
var data = {}
data.number = "1"
```

So really this is more of a "how JavaScript works" question rather than being about mongoose validation.

Comment: Yep....this proves to be true and very useful...just tested it. But, I would assume the writers of Mongoose took this in consideration and wrote their own validation for this, correct?  I would like leave as unanswered until I can get to the bottom of this because otherwise it is a major flaw in type checking on a schema.

Comment: @dman It's not really a flaw but just how JavaScript works. It really isn't strongly typed such as Java,C,C++,C# etc. If you really want you can add pre-save hooks to your field and verify via `typeof` in order to throw an error. But I think most people familiar with JavaScript will be aware of the `.toString()` behavior  and would not expect anything different from marking a field as type String.

Comment: This was verified from another source that this is the expected behavior. Kind of silly to have types that aren't used as types, but oh well.